# Get historical stock data with delisted tickers

Tags: python, finance, stock, yfinance, back-testing

I need to get historical stock data of S&P 500 including delisted tickers for backtesting in Python.

I tried to parse wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies), then download data

```
yf.download(delisted_tickers)
```

but i can't get big part of data because of that error

`No data found, symbol may be delisted`

So, are there other methods to get all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Only Premium Plus members can view delisted company data"**

Source : https://finance.yahoo.com/news/premium-plus-feature-historical-financial-201155209.html

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about yfinance plus. But it would better to find free method

Comment: @DanilaMusaev Yes yahoo has some special tools for premium user, i guess it's not accessible if you use yfinance. You could use Selenium to build a robot that allows you to connect (having premium account), naviguate to the delisted stocks and download historical data but I don't know if that worth it .. :D

Answer (score -1):

im pretty sure `yfinance` only pulls stock data of current stocks, but you can give it a time frame, for example:

```
# Define the ticker list
import pandas as pd
tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'WMT', 'IBM', 'MU', 'BA', 'AXP']

# Fetch the data
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers_list,'2015-1-1')['Adj Close']

# Print first 5 rows of the data
print(data.head())
```

Comment: not working. i tried this to get XLNX prices that was removed in 2022-02-15 => not found